# '사동' means causative, but what about '주동'?

Tags: grammar, verb

Just like 수동(passive) is the opposite of 능동(active), 주동 is the opposite of 사동(causative). How can I say 주동 in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no single standard or common English language equivalent to 주동 as used in Korean linguistics, as it is considered to be the "root" form. Translations used for 주동사 include:

> **principal verb**
>
> **basic form**
>
> **[non-causative verb](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=p2aqCQAAQBAJ)**